# Launching an Activity from a home screen widget via onReceive

Tags: android, widget

I am attempting to fire off an activity from a home screen widget when I send an refresh intent from a background server or activity. When debugging I can see the intent action but this method does not work. I have buttons on my widget that leverage Pending Intents but cannot figure out to make Pending intents work in this situation and the standard method used in an activity does not work. Any thoughts?

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)         
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    {
       if (intent.getAction().equals("myapp.action.REFRESHMSGS")) 
       {    
           GetMessages();           
           launchMsgReaderAct(context);
       }
    }

    private void launchMsgReaderAct(Context context)
    {
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setClass(context,MsgRdr.class); 
     context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Comment: What does your manifest xml file look like?